# How to add a registration progress tracker in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add a progress tracker in my registration form on Xamarin Forms, but somehow I cant find a plugin that works and am stuck here. What im looking for is something like this:

[image]

Where step 1, step 2, step 3, and complete all have different names.

Comment: a simple way to approach it would be to create a separate png/svg for each state of the progress bar, and then swap them out as the user moves forward

Comment: @Jason This won't work very well across different device classes

Comment: Why not?  If you use an SVG it will scale as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to implement something alike would be a view (let's call it `StepBar`) containing a `StackLayout` to implement the steps.

The simplest option would be a list of strings defining the steps, that would be translated to the contents of the `StackLayout` (**please bear in mind** that this is a very basic example, which gives you a starting point, but needs some work to be done to get production ready)

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _steps;

public ObservableCollection<string> Steps
{
    get
    {
        if (this._steps == null)
        {
            this._steps = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            this._steps.CollectionChanged += this.OnStepsChanged;
        }

        return this._steps;
    }
}
```

along with a `SelectedStep` bindable property

```
public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedStepProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SelectedStep), typeof(int), typeof(StepBar), 0, propertyChanged: SelectedStepChanged);

public int SelectedStep
{
    get => (int)this.GetValue(SelectedStepProperty);
    set => this.SetValue(SelectedStepProperty, value);
}
```

In your `OnStepChanged` method you will create the controls displaying the steps

```
private void OnStepsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this._stackLayout.Children.Clear();

    foreach (var step in this._steps.Select((step, index) => new{StepName=step, Index=index}))
    {
        var selected = this._steps.IndexOf(step.StepName) <= this.SelectedStep;

        if (step.Index > 0)
        {
            this._stackLayout.Children.Add(
                new BoxView { BackgroundColor = selected ? Color.Aquamarine : Color.Black, HeightRequest = 1, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center });
        }

        var button = new Button
                         {
                             Text = step.StepName,
                             HeightRequest = 80,
                             WidthRequest = 80,
                             CornerRadius = 40,
                             BackgroundColor = selected ? Color.Aquamarine : Color.LightGray,
                         };
        button.Clicked += (_, __) => this.SelectedStep = step.Index; 
        this._stackLayout.Children.Add(button);
    }
}
```

The `StackLayout` is initialized in the construtor:

```
public StepBar()
{
    this.Visual = new VisualMarker.MaterialVisual();
    this._stackLayout = new StackLayout
                            {
                                Spacing = 0,
                                Margin = 20,
                                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
                            };
    this.Content = this._stackLayout;
}
```

(I've used the new Xamarin.Forms 3.6 `Visual` property for the buttons to be round. It will give you errors with older versions of Xamarin.Forms.)

The only thing to do now, is to color the steps up to the selected step, when `SelectedStep` changes. For that purpose I've implemented the `SelectedStepChanged` handler

```
private static void SelectedStepChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
{
    if (bindable is StepBar stepBar)
    {
        stepBar.OnSelectedStepChanged((int)newvalue);
    }
}

private void OnSelectedStepChanged(int selectedStep)
{
    this.UncolorAll();
    for (var step = 0; step <= selectedStep; step++)
    {
        this.ColorStep(step);
    }
}

private void UncolorAll()
{
    foreach (var button in this._stackLayout.Children.OfType<Button>())
    {
        button.BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray;
    }

    foreach (var boxView in this._stackLayout.Children.OfType<BoxView>())
    {
        boxView.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
    }
}

private void ColorStep(int step)
{
    var button = this._stackLayout.Children.OfType<Button>().ElementAt(step);
    button.BackgroundColor = Color.Aquamarine;

    var boxViews = this._stackLayout.Children.OfType<BoxView>();
    if (boxViews.Count() > step - 1 && step > 0)
    {
        var boxView = boxViews.ElementAt(step - 1);
        boxView.BackgroundColor = Color.Aquamarine;
    }
}
```

If you don't want the user to change between the steps, you could of course replace the buttons by simple shapes. Since `SelectedStep` is bindable, you can easily bind it to a viewmodel.